# Search a min/max value in array with function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new with PHP and my professor asked me to find a min and max value in a array with function.
I did it with `foreach` and `if` but I have no idea how to do it with a `function` .. 
Here is my PHP

```
    <?php 

$nb1 =  $_POST['nb1'];
$nb2 =  $_POST['nb2'];
$nb3 =  $_POST['nb3'];
$nb4 =  $_POST['nb4'];

$tabnumber = array( $nb1,
                    $nb2,
                    $nb3,
                    $nb4);

$min = $tabnumber['0'];

$max = $tabnumber['0'];


foreach($tabnumber as $number)
{
    if($number<$min)
    {
        $min = $number;
    }
}

echo '<p>Le minimum est: '.$min.'</p>';

foreach($tabnumber as $number)
{
    if($number>$max)
    {
        $max = $number;
    }
}

echo '<p>Le maximum est: '.$max.'</p>';

?>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+max

Comment: Wow .. didn't know about this function ... I was trying to do it by myself ... Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please add an answer post below to describe what the solution was, thanks.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

For academic purposes, this is how you create a function to retrieve the minimum value of an array:

```
function getMinimum (array $array) {
    // assume the 1st element is the minimum
    $min = $array[0]; 

    // iterate through the array
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        // if you find a value that's smallest than the
        // minimum, update the minimum
        if ($min < $value) {
            $min = $value;
        }
    }

    // now return the minimum value
    return $min;
}

// invoke the function
$min = getMinimum($tabnumber);
```

However, if you don't need to create your own - it's not clear what the purpose of the exercise is - you can use PHP's build it [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use min function to find min and max value.

```
$tabnumber = array( 9,3,5,2);
echo min($tabnumber);//2
echo max($tabnumber);//9
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Answer (score 0):

Check for PHP functions before trying to implement your own logic:

```
$min = min($tabnumber);
$max = max($tabnumber);
```

Without those and without a loop (for fun):

```
sort($tabnumber);
$min = reset($tabnumber); //or $tabnumber[0]
$max = end($tabnumber);
```